# Highest kill count of the Big E in one action

Tags: warhammer-40k, kill-count

**How many creatures has the [emperor of mankind](http://img0.reactor.cc/pics/post/Emperor-of-Mankind-Imperium-Warhammer-40000-%D1%84%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B-5847888.jpeg) killed in one action?**

- He must have performed the action himself.
- Devices created by him and used by someone else do not count.
- Ordering things does not count either

Book sources are welcome but not mandatory

State 31/06/2020

Comment: Does [the Astronomican](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Astronomican) count?  It's the Emperor himself who creates and directs it (although he draws the energy to do it from others it is still him who makes it), it could be argued as being one continual action, and it kills up to 1000 human psykers *every day,* in perpetuity.

Comment: @Steve-O Well, I was hoping for an exploding planet, but the Astronomican counts and will probably be hard to beat

Comment: Well 1000 per day for the 10-12.000 year history of the Empire "only" ends up at some 4.3 billion, there are probably individuals with a higher kill-count than that - a single Exterminatus on a moderately populated planet for example. Though those are orders given not personal actions, of course.

If consequences of actions count, then the Emperor instigating the Primarch program (or the Space Marina program) would vastly outnumber the Astronomican.

Answer (score 2):

In the book Master of Mankind at the end the emperor destroys all the demons, traitor marines, traitor titans and everything else in the web way within a large radius of the holding point. No number is given but it is a lot all in one moment.